# Selection Sort based on 2D lists

Tags: python

I have a quick question about selection sort method based on Python. I have created this example to help me better understand the concept.

```
 John,2,5 
 Jill,4,5
 Randy,3,6
```

(organized by name, age, height).

I have to be able to convert this list into a 2d array and use a selection sort and pick the nth number

for example:

```
age(2)
```

result would be:

```
Randy,3,6
```

It goes through in order and finds the age of each person and arranges in lowest to highest, then when selecting age(n) n would be the place in the sorted array.

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

Unclear question, or lack of one, but this seems likely to be what you wanted.

```
from operator import itemgetter

mylist = [["John",2,5], ["Jill",4,6], ["Randy",3,6]]

mylist.sort(key=itemgetter(1))

age = lambda x: mylist[x-1]

print age(2)
```

> output: ['Randy', 3, 6]